# last_update flag of user data also changed when user changes address details?

Tags: api

I'm accessing the magento store via v1 soap api.
User details have a last_update flag that tells me when the last change has been.

Does anyone here know if this flag also changes if a user changes his/her adress details? Or do I have to check the adress flags too if I wish to be sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the customer and address are separate entities, they both maintain a separate value for `updated_at` in their respective tables in the DB.

Doing a quick test showed that changing the user address didn't change the `last_updated` value for the customer entity.

Comment: You're right, when an adress exists and is edited the user flag doesn't change. 
It does however change when you edit it from the admin end... So much for consistency...